# Problem with list of figures

Tags: hyperref

Why when I insert list of figure, there are something error like 
Bad math environment delimiter. ...ikel hijau dan lingkaran merah\relax }}{14}?

Comment: You're using the fragile command `\(`...`\)` in your captions. Use `$`...`$` or load the package [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e).

Comment: yes thats work....  i replace `\( \)` with `$ $`

Comment: Then consider upvoting the posts in the mentioned link...